# Fatal error: Uncaught exception bypass

Tags: php, include, fatal-error

I'm working on a PHP Status script, it's using a php class someone else wrote, what I'm including in me PHP script(include_once()).

If one of the server is down what this script it trying to check, the class will throw a Fatal error: Uncaught exception error.

Is there a way to bypass this? So it would just return 0 or something.

This is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'No content was received back from McMyAdmin.' in /var/www/admin/mcmyadmin.class.php:1233 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/admin/mcmyadmin.class.php(822): McMyAdmin->request(Array) #1 /var/www/admin/mcmyadmin.class.php(22): McMyAdmin->login('admin', '1337Hax', 'localhost', 9000) #2 /var/www/admin/hub.php(14): McMyAdmin->__construct('admin', 'removed', 'localhost', 9000) #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/admin/mcmyadmin.class.php on line 1233
```

This is the mcmyadmin.class.php file:

```
<?php
/***********************************
* McMyAdmin PHP API class.
* Author: Alan Farquharson
* Version: 0.5 - (McMyAdmin V:2.4.3.4)
***********************************/

class McMyAdmin {

protected $response;
protected $config = array();
protected $logged_in = false;
protected $session_id = null;

/**
* __construct - Optional Params. If chosen, script will login.
* User      Pass    Host    Port
* String    String  String  String
*/
public function __construct($user = 'admin',$pass = '',$host = 'localhost',$port = '8080') {
    if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass) && !empty($host) && !empty($port)) {
        $this->login($user,$pass,$host,$port);
    }
}

/**
* Method addGroupValue
* Group Type    Value   
* String    String  String  
*/
public function addGroupValue ($group, $type, $value) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$group || !$type || !$value) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'addgroupvalue' , 'group' => $group, 'type' => $type, 'value' => $value));
}


/**
* Method addLicence
* NewKey    
* String    
*/
public function addLicence ($newkey) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$newkey) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'addlicence' , 'newkey' => $newkey));
}


/**
* Method addScheduleItem
* Hours Mins    Type    Param   
* Int32 Int32   EventType [Enum:Int32]  String  
*/
public function addScheduleItem ($hours, $mins, $type, $param) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$hours || !$mins || !$type || !$param) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'addscheduleitem' , 'hours' => $hours, 'mins' => $mins, 'type' => $type, 'param' => $param));
}


/**
* Method backupWorld
* Label 
* String    
*/
public function backupWorld ($label) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$label) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'backupworld' , 'label' => $label));
}


/**
* Method changePassword
* OldPassword   NewPassword 
* String    String  
*/
public function changePassword ($oldpassword, $newpassword) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$oldpassword || !$newpassword) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'changepassword' , 'oldpassword' => $oldpassword, 'newpassword' => $newpassword));
}


/**
* Method changeUserPassword
* Username  NewPassword 
* String    String  
*/
public function changeUserPassword ($username, $newpassword) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$username || !$newpassword) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'changeuserpassword' , 'username' => $username, 'newpassword' => $newpassword));
}


/**
* Method createUser
* NewUsername   
* String    
*/
public function createUser ($newusername) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$newusername) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'createuser' , 'newusername' => $newusername));
}


/**
* Method deleteBackup
* Index 
* Int32 
*/
public function deleteBackup ($index) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$index) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'deletebackup' , 'index' => $index));
}


/**
* Method deleteUser
* Username  
* String    
*/
public function deleteUser ($username) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$username) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'deleteuser' , 'username' => $username));
}


/**
* Method deleteWorld
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function deleteWorld () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'deleteworld'));
}


/**
* Method delScheduleItem
* Index 
* Int32 
*/
public function delScheduleItem ($index) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$index) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'delscheduleitem' , 'index' => $index));
}


/**
* Method doDiagnostics
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function doDiagnostics () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'dodiagnostics'));
}


/**
* Method getAllGroupInfo
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getAllGroupInfo () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getallgroupinfo'));
}


/**
* Method getBackupList
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getBackupList () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getbackuplist'));
}


/**
* Method getBackupStatus
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getBackupStatus () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getbackupstatus'));
}


/**
* Method getChat
* Since 
* Int64 
*/
public function getChat ($since) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$since) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getchat' , 'since' => $since));
}


/**
* Method getConfig
* Key   
* String    
*/
public function getConfig ($key) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$key) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getconfig' , 'key' => $key));
}


/**
* Method getDeleteStatus
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getDeleteStatus () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getdeletestatus'));
}


/**
* Method getFullConfig
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getFullConfig () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getfullconfig'));
}


/**
* Method getGroupInfo
* Group 
* String    
*/
public function getGroupInfo ($group) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$group) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getgroupinfo' , 'group' => $group));
}


/**
* Method getGroupList
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getGroupList () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getgrouplist'));
}


/**
* Method getMCMAUsers
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getMCMAUsers () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getmcmausers'));
}


/**
* Method getPluginCategories
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getPluginCategories () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getplugincategories'));
}


/**
* Method getPlugins
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getPlugins () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getplugins'));
}


/**
* Method getProviderInfo
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getProviderInfo () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getproviderinfo'));
}


/**
* Method getRestoreStatus
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getRestoreStatus () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getrestorestatus'));
}


/**
* Method getSchedule
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getSchedule () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getschedule'));
}


/**
* Method getServerInfo
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getServerInfo () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getserverinfo'));
}


/**
* Method getStatus
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getStatus () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getstatus'));
}


/**
* Method getTip
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getTip () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'gettip'));
}


/**
* Method getUpdateStatus
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getUpdateStatus () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getupdatestatus'));
}


/**
* Method getVersions
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getVersions () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getversions'));
}


/**
* Method killServer
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function killServer () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'killserver'));
}


/**
* Method logout
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function logout () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'logout'));
}


/**
* Method reload
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function reload () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'reload'));
}


/**
* Method removeGroupValue
* Group Type    Value   
* String    String  String  
*/
public function removeGroupValue ($group, $type, $value) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$group || !$type || !$value) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'removegroupvalue' , 'group' => $group, 'type' => $type, 'value' => $value));
}


/**
* Method restartServer
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function restartServer () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'restartserver'));
}


/**
* Method restoreBackup
* Index 
* Int32 
*/
public function restoreBackup ($index) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$index) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'restorebackup' , 'index' => $index));
}


/**
* Method runScheduleItem
* Index 
* Int32 
*/
public function runScheduleItem ($index) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$index) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'runscheduleitem' , 'index' => $index));
}


/**
* Method scanPlugins
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function scanPlugins () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'scanplugins'));
}


/**
* Method sendChat
* Message   
* String    
*/
public function sendChat ($message) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$message) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'sendchat' , 'message' => $message));
}


/**
* Method setConfig
* Key   Value   
* String    String  
*/
public function setConfig ($key, $value) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$key || !$value) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'setconfig' , 'key' => $key, 'value' => $value));
}


/**
* Method setGroupDefaults
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function setGroupDefaults () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'setgroupdefaults'));
}


/**
* Method setMCMAUserAuthMask
* User  Mask    
* String    UInt64  
*/
public function setMCMAUserAuthMask ($user, $mask) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$user || !$mask) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'setmcmauserauthmask' , 'user' => $user, 'mask' => $mask));
}


/**
* Method setMCMAUserSettingMask
* User  Mask    
* String    UInt32  
*/
public function setMCMAUserSettingMask ($user, $mask) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$user || !$mask) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'setmcmausersettingmask' , 'user' => $user, 'mask' => $mask));
}


/**
* Method setPluginState
* Plugin    State   
* String    Boolean 
*/
public function setPluginState ($plugin, $state) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$plugin || !$state) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'setpluginstate' , 'plugin' => $plugin, 'state' => $state));
}


/**
* Method setScheduleDefaults
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function setScheduleDefaults () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'setscheduledefaults'));
}


/**
* Method startServer
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function startServer () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'startserver'));
}


/**
* Method stopServer
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function stopServer () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'stopserver'));
}


/**
* Method unsetMCMAUserAuthMask
* User  Mask    
* String    UInt64  
*/
public function unsetMCMAUserAuthMask ($user, $mask) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$user || !$mask) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'unsetmcmauserauthmask' , 'user' => $user, 'mask' => $mask));
}


/**
* Method unsetMCMAUserSettingMask
* User  Mask    
* String    UInt32  
*/
public function unsetMCMAUserSettingMask ($user, $mask) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$user || !$mask) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'unsetmcmausersettingmask' , 'user' => $user, 'mask' => $mask));
}


/**
* Method updateMC
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function updateMC () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'updatemc'));
}


/**
* Method updateMCMA
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function updateMCMA () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'updatemcma'));
}

/**
* Method getBukgetPluginInfo
* PluginName    
* String    
*/
public function getBukgetPluginInfo ($pluginname) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$pluginname) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getbukgetplugininfo' , 'pluginname' => $pluginname));
}

/**
* Method getTokenAuth
* Username  
* String    
*/
public function getTokenAuth ($username) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$username) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'gettokenauth' , 'username' => $username));
}

/**
* Method searchBukgetByName
* Name  
* String    
*/
public function searchBukgetByName ($name) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$name) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'searchbukgetbyname' , 'name' => $name));
}

/**
* Method uploadBackup
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function uploadBackup () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'uploadbackup'));
}

/**
* Method Login - Used to login to the McMyAdmin server with the supplied details.
* User      Pass    Host    Port
* String    String  String  String
*/
public function login($user = 'admin',$pass = '',$host = 'localhost',$port = '8080') {

    if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass) && !empty($host) && !empty($port)) {
        $this->config['user'] = $user;
        $this->config['pass'] = $pass;
        $this->config['host'] = $host;
        $this->config['port'] = $port;

        $request = $this->request(array('req'=>'login', 'Username'=>$user, 'Password'=>$pass));

        if (isset($request->MCMASESSIONID)) {
            $this->session_id = $request->MCMASESSIONID;
        }

        if($request->success == 1){
            $this->logged_in = true;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Incorrect config details');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Not enough Paramters');
    }

}

/**
* Method getLoggedIn
* This allows a method to see if user is logged in or not.
*/
private function ensureLoggedIn() {
    if($this->logged_in == false) {
        throw new Exception('Not logged into McMyAdmin');
    }
}

/**
* Method getPlayers()
* returns PlayerList
*/
public function getPlayers() {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();
    $request = $this->getStatus();
    $playerlist = array();

    if(isset($request->userinfo)) {
        foreach($request->userinfo as $user => $values) {
            $playerlist[] = $user;
        }
    }

    return $playerlist;
}

/**
* Method downloadPluginFromURL
* URL   
* String    
*/
public function downloadPluginFromURL ($url) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$url) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'downloadpluginfromurl' , 'url' => $url));
}

/**
* Method getBukgetCategories
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getBukgetCategories () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getbukgetcategories'));
}

/**
* Method getExtensions
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function getExtensions () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getextensions'));
}

/**
* Method renameGroup
* Group NewName 
* String    String  
*/
public function renameGroup ($group, $newname) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$group || !$newname) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'renamegroup' , 'group' => $group, 'newname' => $newname));
}

        /**
* Method downloadBukgetPlugin
* PluginName    
* String    
*/
public function downloadBukgetPlugin ($pluginname) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$pluginname) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'downloadbukgetplugin' , 'pluginname' => $pluginname));
}

/**
* Method emcSetConfig
* Key   Value   
* String    String  
*/
public function emcSetConfig ($key, $value) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$key || !$value) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'emcsetconfig' , 'key' => $key, 'value' => $value));
}

/**
* Method getBukgetPluginsInCategory
* CategoryName  Start   
* String    Int32   
*/
public function getBukgetPluginsInCategory ($categoryname, $start) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$categoryname || !$start) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'getbukgetpluginsincategory' , 'categoryname' => $categoryname, 'start' => $start));
}

/**
* Method searchBukget
* Query 
* String    
*/
public function searchBukget ($query) {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

if(!$query) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
}

return $this->request(array('req' => 'searchbukget' , 'query' => $query));
}

/**
* Method sleepServer
* No Arguments  
*   
*/
public function sleepServer () {
$this->ensureLoggedIn();

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'sleepserver'));
}

/**
 * Method createGroup
 * Name
 * String
 */
public function createGroup ($name) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$name) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'creategroup' , 'name' => $name));
}

/**
 * Method deleteGroup
 * Name
 * String
 */
public function deleteGroup ($name) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$name) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'deletegroup' , 'name' => $name));
}

/**
 * Method deleteLegacyBackup
 * Index
 * Int32
 */
public function deleteLegacyBackup ($index) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$index) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'deletelegacybackup' , 'index' => $index));
}

/**
 * Method getBackups
 * No Arguments
 *
 */
public function getBackups () {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'getbackups'));
}

/**
 * Method getLegacyBackupList
 * No Arguments
 *
 */
public function getLegacyBackupList () {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'getlegacybackuplist'));
}

/**
 * Method getLegacyRestoreStatus
 * No Arguments
 *
 */
public function getLegacyRestoreStatus () {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'getlegacyrestorestatus'));
}

/**
 * Method getRAS
 * No Arguments
 *
 */
public function getRAS () {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'getras'));
}

/**
 * Method getWorlds
 * No Arguments
 *
 */
public function getWorlds () {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'getworlds'));
}

/**
 * Method restoreLegacyBackup
 * Index
 * Int32
 */
public function restoreLegacyBackup ($index) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$index) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'restorelegacybackup' , 'index' => $index));
}

/**
 * Method scanWorlds
 * No Arguments
 *
 */
public function scanWorlds () {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'scanworlds'));
}

/**
 * Method sendRASconfigChange
 * key  value
 * String   String
 */
public function sendRASconfigChange ($key, $value) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$key || !$value) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'sendrasconfigchange' , 'key' => $key, 'value' => $value));
}

/**
 * Method sendRAScursor
 * x    y
 * Int32    Int32
 */
public function sendRAScursor ($x, $y) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$x || !$y) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'sendrascursor' , 'x' => $x, 'y' => $y));
}

/**
 * Method sendRASviewChange
 * view
 * String
 */
public function sendRASviewChange ($view) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$view) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'sendrasviewchange' , 'view' => $view));
}

/**
 * Method setWorldBackup
 * WorldID  Included
 * String   Boolean
 */
public function setWorldBackup ($worldid, $included) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$worldid || !$included) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'setworldbackup' , 'worldid' => $worldid, 'included' => $included));
}

/**
 * Method takeBackup
 * Label    IncludePermissions  IncludePlugins  IncludeConfig   IncludeServer   IncludeWorlds
 * String   Boolean Boolean Boolean Boolean Boolean (Optional - default value is 'True')
 */
public function takeBackup ($label, $includepermissions, $includeplugins, $includeconfig, $includeserver, $includeworlds) {
    $this->ensureLoggedIn();

    if(!$label || !$includepermissions || !$includeplugins || !$includeconfig || !$includeserver || !$includeworlds) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid arguments');
    }

    return $this->request(array('req' => 'takebackup' , 'label' => $label, 'includepermissions' => $includepermissions, 'includeplugins' => $includeplugins, 'includeconfig' => $includeconfig, 'includeserver' => $includeserver, 'includeworlds' => $includeworlds));
}

/**v
* Method request
* This allows a method to send a request to the McMyAdmin data source.
*/
private function request($args = array()) {
    if(empty($this->config['host']) || empty($this->config['port'])) {
        throw new Exception('No host or port has been given');
    }

    if (isset($this->session_id)) {
      $args['MCMASESSIONID'] = $this->session_id;
    } else {
       $args['Token'] = '';
    }

    $param = '';

    if(!empty($args)) {
        $param = http_build_query($args);
    }

    if(!file_exists('cookie.txt')) {
            if(!touch('cookie.txt')) { // You might have to do this yourself.
                throw new Exception('Please create a file named "cookie.txt" and chown it to the webserver and chmod it to 755 (Or alternatively 777 as a last case)');
            }
            chmod('cookie.txt','777');
    }

    $url = 'http://' . $this->config['host'] . ':' . $this->config['port'] . '/data.json?' . $param;
    $ch = curl_init($url);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array('Content-type: application/json','Accept: application/json'));
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Firefox/mozilla McMyAdminClass');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , 'cookie.txt');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE , 'cookie.txt');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
             $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(empty($data)) {
        throw new Exception('No content was received back from McMyAdmin.');
    }
        curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($data);

return $data;
}
    }
```

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/sZv2tecb

Regards Jurre

Comment: use try/catch control structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing:

```
try{
include_once("...");
}
```